# How to find cloud condition using open weather map api using python

Tags: python, json, python-requests, openweathermap

I tried to get weather details using Open Weather Map APIs which worked till a point. I want to find the description of the clouds (scattered, heavy etc) and I am getting a keyword error which I am unable to correct

This is the code I have written-

```
import requests , json

apiKey = "d5f6e96071109af97ee3b206fe8cb0cb"

baseURL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city name}&appid={API key}"

cityName = "ranchi"

completeURL = f"https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={cityName}&appid={apiKey}"

response = requests.get(completeURL)

data = response.json()

print(data)

print("Minimum Temperature ",data["main"]["temp_min"])
print("Maximum Temperature ",data["main"]["temp_max"])
print("Temperature ",data["main"]["pressure"])
print("Visibility ",data["visibility"])
print("Humidity ",data["main"]["humidity"])

print("Clouds ",data["weather"]["description"])
```

This is the error (of the last print statement) I am getting-

```
line 23, in <module>
    print("Clouds ",data["weather"]["description"])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

What is the keyword I am missing ?

Comment: Try using weatherdbi.herokuapp.com. Though it is very new, it is very easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, this is an excerpt of the output of the API call:

```
"coord": {
    "lon": 85.3333, 
    "lat": 23.35
  }, 
  "weather": [{
    "id": 802, 
    "main": "Clouds", 
    "description": "scattered clouds"
  }], 
  "main": {
    "temp": 312.21, 
    "feels_like": 310.96
    ....
```

If you look closely, you will notice that, for example, `main` directly references a json object. So you can refer to `data["main"]["humidity"]` and expect it to work. However, `weather` references a list, not a json object. So referring to it as `data["weather"]["description"]` will assume that `description` is the index of the weather list.

To solve the issue, you only need to provide the index first (0 in this case) like so:

```
data["weather"][0]["description"]
```

And everything should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping all same except **data["weather"][0]["description"]** because the "weather" key has a list of values from which you have to get a "description".

I Hope, it solves your problem!

```
import requests , json

apiKey = "d5f6e96071109af97ee3b206fe8cb0cb"

baseURL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city name}&appid={API key}"

cityName = "ranchi"

completeURL = f"https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={cityName}&appid={apiKey}"

response = requests.get(completeURL)

data = response.json()

print(data)

print("Minimum Temperature ",data["main"]["temp_min"])
print("Maximum Temperature ",data["main"]["temp_max"])
print("Temperature ",data["main"]["pressure"])
print("Visibility ",data["visibility"])
print("Humidity ",data["main"]["humidity"])

print("Clouds ",data["weather"][0]["description"])
```